# Global variable get corrupted after software interrupt

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls

I'm currently learning x86 assembly language at school, so I could ask a dumb question (though I found nothing useful).

I have some global variables declared in the *data* section in the main file, and then I have a second file where there are two functions that use these global variables.

```
.section .data
  .globl file_desc
  .globl init
  .globl reset
  .globl rpm

  file_desc: .long
  init: .int
  reset: .int
  rpm: .long
```

In the _start section, I call the *sys_open* syscall for getting the file descriptor and I save it in the *file_desc* variable.
Then I call a function in the other file:

```
read_init:
    # read the INIT and convert it
    movl $SYS_READ, %eax
    movl file_desc, %ebx
    leal init, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80

    cmp $0, %eax        # check for EOF
    jle eof
    jmp get_init

eof:
    movl $47, init      # we make the init to -1 xD

get_init:
    subb $48, init      # get the real value of INIT

    # skip 1 byte
    movl $SYS_SEEK, %eax
    movl file_desc, %ebx
    movl $1, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80

    ret
```

The problem is that when I reach the *sys_lseek* syscall, file_desc has been modified! I debugged with GDB to see it and after calling the read syscall the value is not the same.

In theory it shouldn't modify it, so what the heck is doing my program?

Comment: You need to define values, such as `.long 0`. As you have done, you haven't allocated any space and all your variables overlap.

Comment: Ehm... I feel so stupid... Now it works! Thanks :)

Comment: If they're going to be zero-initialized, they should go in the `.bss` section.  No point in having zeros in the object file.